# php if else show statement - date dependent like. show if date=Dec. 2, 2010 or less than?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I updated my photo-gallery framework recently. But I still need the old 'javascript files' in stories older than a certain date, eg: Dec. 2, 2010. (stories are in CMS/dynamic)

I was thinking of an "if else" statement, but can't get it right.

```
if date(Dec. 2, 2010) < CURDATE() {
                 show this (which is the older JS files) ; }
else {
                 show the new javascript files; }
```

I don't like having to load both of the JS files if I don't need to (for speed sake).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if (time() > strtotime('2010-12-02')) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highslide/highslide.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/highslide/highslide.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            hs.graphicsDir = "/js/highslide/graphics/";
            hs.wrapperClassName = "wide-border";
            hs.showCredits = false;
        </script>';
}
else {
  echo 'old stuff';
}
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highslide/highslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/highslide/highslide.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 hs.graphicsDir = '/js/highslide/graphics/';
 hs.wrapperClassName = 'wide-border';
 hs.showCredits = false;
</script>

Comment: Include what?  I'll assume there are script tags you tried to post?

Comment: yeah, i have 3 or 4 javascript include files and a css file too. Wondering if the quotes will break the code?

Comment: Modified my response so you can see how you can display the script tags.  However, displaying things is very, very basic PHP.  I think you should read the getting started pages in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: Here is a great intro read so you know how to handle quotes within strings too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: you are the MAN. Thank you very much. I am getting my feet wet. I can read php really really well. But writing it causes some trouble. I am getting better though.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the line of

```
if date(Dec. 2, 2010) < CURDATE() {
     <script src="old_js.js" />
else {
     <script src="new_js.js" />
```